# Как сделать чтобы функция работала без учета регистра

Tags: java

Задача:

> Прочитать текст из файла и написать функцию, которая
> считает количество вхождений некоторой строки в этот
> текст без учета регистра символов. Сама функция должна работать без учета регистра.
> Использовать цикл и `indexOf`, который принимает начальный индекс, с которого искать.

Просьба подсказать, как сделать функцию без учета регистра? Возможно, через регулярные выражения.

Код.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OccurrencesCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String searchString = "word";

        File file = new File("out.txt");
        System.out.println("Количество вхождений подстроки " + searchString + " = " + getOccurrencesCount(searchString, file));
    }

    public static int getOccurrencesCount(String searchString, File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            int occurrencesCount = 0;

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String inputString = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                int searchStringStartIndex = 0;

                while (true) {
                    searchStringStartIndex = searchString.indexOf(inputString,searchStringStartIndex);

                    if (searchStringStartIndex < 0) {
                        break;
                    }

                    occurrencesCount++;

                    searchStringStartIndex += searchString.length();
                }
            }

            return occurrencesCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы и так практически написали функцию, которая работает без учёта регистра. Остаётся только, помимо регистра каждой строки файла, понижать и регистр искомой подстроки `searchString`, и тогда функция действительно будет регистронезависимой.

К примеру, чтобы не понижать регистр искомой подстроки каждый раз, это можно сделать вот так в самом начале работы функции:

```
searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
```

С другой стороны, в коде есть другая проблема. Строка

```
searchStringStartIndex = searchString.indexOf(inputString,searchStringStartIndex);
```

некорректна. Она у вас ищет вхождение строки в подстроку, а не наоборот. Её надо применять к исходной строке, а в качестве параметра передавать подстроку, то есть:

```
searchStringStartIndex = inputString.indexOf(searchString, searchStringStartIndex);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Можете подсказать Строки являются неизменяемыми объектами. Все функции, которые работают со строками, возвращают новые строки, а старые – остаются без изменения.  searchString = searchString.toLowerCase(); получается  ссылаемся на старый объект . Новый не создаем ?

Comment: Первая часть рассуждений - да, вторая - нет. Да, строки неизменяемые и функции с ними возвращают новые объекты, старые не трогают. Нет, когда мы делаем `toLowerCase()`, то мы как раз-таки создаём новый объект, присваивая ссылку на него старой переменной. То есть, ссылка на старый объект затирается, и в общем случае старый объект удалился бы сборщиком мусора. Но для строк есть *пул строк*, поэтому прежний объект - изначальная строка - останется в нём.

Comment: т.е это было бы равносильно String searchStringLo = searchString.toLowerCase();  далее searchStringStartIndex = inputString.indexOf(searchStringLo , searchStringStartIndex); ?

Comment: Ну да. Просто в одном случае вы присваиваете новую ссылку старой переменной, а в другом - новой отдельной переменной.